# Very different performance on similar machines while performing JOIN

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a simple query joining two tables (about 200k rows). I use MySQL Workbench 6.2.

```
CREATE TABLE joined AS SELECT table1.id,
    table1.Penetration,
    table1.Code,    
    table1.Badness,
    table2.Code AS Code_new 
    FROM
    table1
        INNER JOIN
    table2 ON table1.id= table2.id;
```

On MacBook Air 2011 (Intel i5 1.7 GHz, 4GB RAM) that query takes ~2.3 seconds.
On other, more powerful, Windows10 machine (Intel i5, 2.3GHz, 8GB RAM) that query takes 40 minutes). Unlike MacBook the Windows machine doesn't have SSD, but tables are small enough to be loaded into memory (raw CSV files of these  are 11Mb only).

Why is that taking so long and what can be done to improve performance ?

Comment: Maybe you want to look at the [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) output

Comment: Too little information to attempt to provide any explanation. We do not know if the indexes are the same in both servers, how much free memory each sytems has, what other processes running on both servers, if you configured your virus scanner to exclude the directory where the data files are.

Comment: Neither server had any indexes. Indexing the id in both tables, as per Prakash answer, has solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before run the query, try to do the indexing the id in Both tables.